# separation table specification Revit 2015

Tags: c#, api, revit

Sorry for my English.
how to implement the separation of specification tables placed on the sheet?

In any case, I attach a screen what i want.
If there is a "method", i would like to get a solution for the 2015 version.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not available in the API. There is no member on the [ScheduleSheetInstance](http://www.revitapidocs.com/2016/68db8e46-90de-6b54-3dae-598957d94201.htm) to do that.

Comment: it's sad ( I try to find another way